# How to best provide deeplinking to a firestore backed paginated list

Tags: pagination, google-cloud-firestore

I'm evaluating the feasibility to replace parts of our SQL database with Firestore and so far it's been a pleasure!

I'm wondering what's the best way to provide bookmarkable links to a given page in a list? I've successfully implemented paging, and found out that I need to maintain

```
lastVisible: firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot[] = []
```

to be able to traverse back and forth the paginated list like this:

```
if (this._paginator._pageIndex - 1 in this.lastVisible) {
  return ref.orderBy('date', 'desc').startAfter(this.lastVisible[this._paginator._pageIndex - 1]).limit(this._paginator.pageSize)
} else {
  return ref.orderBy('date', 'desc').limit(this._paginator.pageSize)
}
```

If I understand correctly, I can feed either the whole doc or the value used by the index to the startAfter and startAt methods. Either way, to provide a a deeplink for the list, opened at page 245, I need to pass 245 values in the URL to be able to pull this one off?

Or then I need to requery all the items from 0 to xxx page and record all the last items?

Any thoughts how to best tackle this one?

Is there any way to just use the numeric indexes, that can be calculated from the page and page size?